# How to make slider from array of objects javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const slidesShop = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-shop');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-shop');
const slideOne = document.getElementById('slide-1');
const slideTwo = document.getElementById('slide-2');
const slideThree = document.getElementById('slide-3');
const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const next = document.getElementById('next');

const bikes = [{
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'L',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  },
  {
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'XL',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  }
]

let activeSlide = 0;
let bikesCount = 10;

const changeSlide = () => {
  slidesShop.forEach((page) => {
    page.classList.remove('active-1');
    slidesShop[activeSlide].classList.add('active-1');
  });
};

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide--;
  if (activeSlide < 0) {
    activeSlide = slidesShop.length - 1;
  }
  changeSlide();
  showBikes();
});

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide++;
  if (activeSlide > slidesShop.length - 1) {
    activeSlide = 0;
  }
  changeSlide();
  showBikes();
});

const showBikes = () => {
  slideOne.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= bikesCount; i++) {
    bikes.forEach((bikes) => {
      const {
        name,
        size,
        type,
        price,
        text_line
      } = bikes;

      const slideShopItem = document.createElement('div');
      slideShopItem.classList.add('slide-shop-item');

      slideShopItem.innerHTML = `
          <img src="img/about.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="item-content">
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>
              ${text_line}
            </p>
            <small>Size: <span>${size}</span></small>
            <small>Type: <span>${type}</span></small>
            <small>Price: <span>${price}$</span></small>
          </div>
      `;
      slideOne.appendChild(slideShopItem);
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="slider-shop">
  <div class="slide-shop active-1" id="slide-1"></div>
  <div class="slide-shop" id="slide-2"></div>
  <div class="slide-shop" id="slide-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons-shop-container">
  <button id="prev">&#11164;</button>
  <button id="next">&#11166;</button>
</div>
```

I have an array of objects like this, just with more objects than two:

```js
const bikes = [
  {
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'L',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line:
      'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  },
  {
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'XL',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line:
      'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  }
]
```

and my question is: is it possible to make a slider that will show 10 objects from an array in each slide? So FIRST slide 10 objects, then SECOND slide other 10 objects, then THIRD slide next 10 objects?

The problem with this code is that it shows me all objects in one slide. I would like to separate them into more slides. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I don’t fully understand your code. what’s `slideShop` ?  Could you provide the rest of the code to make this a working exampe.  Some variables aren’t define here.

Comment: And also, could you provide the `changeSlide` function

Comment: I add full javascript code is it ok now?

Comment: So if i understand correctly, what you want is that every time you click on the arrow it show the next page with other object ?

Comment: Exactly that if it's possible :/ and also when you click prev to go back one slide

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

All you need is to map your current data array into another array, containing slides, and each slide should contain a `products` or `items` prop.

Obviously, you'll need to modify your rendering logic and loop through the current slide's products/items and display them accordingly (in a table, or however they make sense in the context of your slide).

A mapper function (which would take in the products and output slides) would look something like:

```
const createSlides = (data, pageSize) => Array.from(
  Array(Math.ceil(data.length / pageSize)).keys()).map(key => ({
    id: `slide-${key + 1}`,
    products: data.slice(key * pageSize, (key + 1) * pageSize)
  })
);
```

... where `data` has your current data.

Here's an implementation example, where I simply added a couple of functions to create randomized data. You don't need anything from it, except the mapper function (written above).

```js
const randomData = Array.from(Array(100).keys()).map(key => ({
  id: 'product-' + (key + 1),
  ...randomProduct(),
}));


const createSlides = (data, pageSize) => Array.from(
  Array(Math.ceil(data.length / pageSize)).keys()).map(key => ({
    id: 'slide-' + (key + 1),
    products: data.slice(key * pageSize, (key + 1) * pageSize)
  })
);

const slides = createSlides(randomData, 10);

console.log(slides);

/* helpers */

function pickRandom(items) {
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
}

function randomProduct() {
  return {
        name: pickRandom(['Trek', 'Bike', 'Hike', 'Rest']),
        size: pickRandom(['L', 'S', 'XS', 'M', 'XL', 'XXL']),
        type: pickRandom(['Mountain Bike', 'Street Bike', 'Motorbike', 'Cycle']),
        price: pickRandom(Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(p => (p + 1) * 1e3)),
        text_line:
          'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
      }
}
```

The `slides` const in the above code (which is also what I'm logging to console) is what you'll have to feed your slider.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array of object:

```js
const bikes = [{
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'L',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  },
  {
    name: 'Trek',
    size: 'XL',
    type: 'Mountain Bike',
    price: 1000,
    text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
  }
]
```

You should make an array of array of object. This way you represents every page with every item in it.

```js
const page = [{
    bikes: [{
        name: 'Trek',
        size: 'L',
        type: 'Mountain Bike',
        price: 1000,
        text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
      },
      {
        name: 'Trek',
        size: 'XL',
        type: 'Mountain Bike',
        price: 1000,
        text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    bikes: [{
      name: 'Super bike',
      size: 'M',
      type: 'Mountain Bike',
      price: 600,
      text_line: 'Lorem ipsum',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    bikes: [{
      name: 'smoll bike',
      size: 'S',
      type: 'Mountain Bike',
      price: 450,
      text_line: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla',
    }, ],
  },
];
```

And to show the active data. use `page[activeSlide].bikes`. every time activeSlide change it will update the data.

```js
const slidesShop = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-shop');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-shop');
const slideOne = document.getElementById('slide-1');
const slideTwo = document.getElementById('slide-2');
const slideThree = document.getElementById('slide-3');
const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const next = document.getElementById('next');


const page = [{
    bikes: [{
        name: 'Trek',
        size: 'L',
        type: 'Mountain Bike',
        price: 1000,
        text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
      },
      {
        name: 'Trek',
        size: 'XL',
        type: 'Mountain Bike',
        price: 1000,
        text_line: 'Bike rides bike of the same something, some, someone!Best with there opinion',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    bikes: [{
      name: 'Super bike',
      size: 'M',
      type: 'Mountain Bike',
      price: 600,
      text_line: 'Lorem ipsum',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    bikes: [{
      name: 'smoll bike',
      size: 'S',
      type: 'Mountain Bike',
      price: 450,
      text_line: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla',
    }, ],
  },
];


let activeSlide = 0;
let bikesCount = 10;

const changeSlide = () => {
  slidesShop.forEach((page) => {
    page.classList.remove('active-1');
    slidesShop[activeSlide].classList.add('active-1');
  });
};

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide--;
  if (activeSlide < 0) {
    activeSlide = slidesShop.length - 1;
  }
  changeSlide();
  showBikes();
});
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeSlide++;
  if (activeSlide > slidesShop.length - 1) {
    activeSlide = 0;
  }
  changeSlide();
  showBikes();
});

const showBikes = () => {
  slideOne.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= bikesCount; i++) {
    page[activeSlide].bikes.forEach((bikes) => {
      const {
        name,
        size,
        type,
        price,
        text_line
      } = bikes;
      const slideShopItem = document.createElement('div');
      slideShopItem.classList.add('slide-shop-item');

      slideShopItem.innerHTML = `
          <img src="img/about.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="item-content">
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>
              ${text_line}
            </p>
            <small>Size: <span>${size}</span></small>
            <small>Type: <span>${type}</span></small>
            <small>Price: <span>${price}$</span></small>
          </div>
    `;
      slideOne.appendChild(slideShopItem);
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="slider-shop">
  <div class="slide-shop active-1" id="slide-1"></div>
  <div class="slide-shop" id="slide-2"></div>
  <div class="slide-shop" id="slide-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="buttons-shop-container">
  <button id="prev">&#11164;</button>
  <button id="next">&#11166;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Providing an answer with no comments on what you've actually changed is not very helpful to the OP or other readers, consider adding comments.

Comment: I understand your point perfectly, but still, even if I put it like this show me the same. Still show me one slide.

Comment: What do you mean by one slide ? When I run this snippet and I click an arrow I see the data change. This is not the case for you ?

Comment: Forgive my mistake, it works perfectly in this snippet here. Thank you for your time.